# AP.NET webforms using LINQ to SQL datasource and databind with foreign keys across multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, linq

I'm attempting to build an asp.net webforms application to serve as the front end of an sql database.

[see database table relations in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmjTu.png)

Simply getting table values is not a problem. 
For example displaying values from 'Item' table like this:

```
var items = from i in db.Items
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = i.Item_ID,
                        Name = i.Name,
                        Barcode = i.BarCode,
                        Description = i.Description,
                        ItemType = i.ItemType1.ItemTypeName,
                        LocationCount = i.Location_Item_Juncs.Count
                    };
        GridView1.DataSource = items;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

[looks like this in webforms webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Cvr.png)

Problem is getting something like supplier information for an item.

**An item can have multiple 'Supplier', 'Location' and 'ReceivedDate'!**

In SQL I can query that information like this:

```
select Supplier.Name, Supplier.Adress, Supplier.Email, Supplier.Phone, Supplier.Supplier_Zipcode
from item, Supp_Company, Supplier
where Item_ID = 8 and  Item_ID = ItemSub_ID and SupplierJunc_ID = Supplier_ID
```

[results look like this in linqpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgfj9.png)

These are the suppliers' information for an item with item id of 8.

Notice, there are 3 tables involved in the query (Item, Supp_Company, Supplier) and 2 pairs of values must match to select valid values.

I want to replicate that query in LINQ to use in my web forms app. 
I believe the solution to this problem will apply to getting locations and 'received dates' for an item as well.

Is it possible to use a similar 'where' clause in LINQ as I can in SQL? What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Have you tried [Linq Joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)?

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, it all depends on the way you build your mappings though. 
you've got a many to many scenario in here and you can

- map entities relying on link table
- map entities relying on link entity

**link table approach** (notice the `modelBuilder HasMany WithMany`)

```
void Main()
{
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        var query = from item in context.Items
                    from supplier in item.Suppliers
                    where item.ItemId == 8
                    select new 
                    {
                        Name = supplier.Name, 
                        Adress = supplier.Address,
                        Email = supplier.Email,
                        Phone = supplier.Phone,
                        Zip = supplier.Zip,
                    };

        //...
    }
}

public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    public YourContext() : base("MyDb")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(item => item.Suppliers)
            .WithMany(supplier => supplier.Items)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("ItemSub_ID");
                m.MapRightKey("SupplierJunc_ID");
                m.ToTable("Supp_Company");
            });
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**link entity approach** (notice the `modelBuilder` maps every table to an entity)

```
void Main()
{
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        var query = from item in context.Items
                    join link in context.SupplierItems
                        on item.ItemId equals link.ItemId
                    join supplier in context.Suppliers
                        on link.SupplierId equals supplier.SupplierId
                    where item.ItemId == 8
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = supplier.Name,
                        Adress = supplier.Address,
                        Email = supplier.Email,
                        Phone = supplier.Phone,
                        Zip = supplier.Zip,
                    };

        //...
    }
}

public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SupplierItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }

    public YourContext() : base("MyDb")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            // ...
            ;

        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
            // ...
            ;

        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierItem>()
            // ...
            ;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: note that as it stands now EF Core does not have support for many to many relationship via link tables, hence one needs to map all tables required for navigation